# Is there a reason to not use google's DNS servers?

Tags: dns, google-dns

I live in the US, using Comcast's internet.

The fact that comcast can see my browsing history bugs me. A **lot**.

I realize that I'm basically having google see it instead of comcast, however google gets it anyway (I use chrome, I use google search, gmail, youtube, andriod, etc...)

I also use a paid VPN, [nVPN](http://nvpn.net).

Is there a reason to **not** use their DNS services? I don't notice any speed changes.

Comment: Even if you use Google's DNS server Comcast can still see your browsing history. If you use a VPN then Comcast already doesn't, Google still gets, what you give them.  Using different DNS servers don't normal provide a detectable speed increase.

Comment: I don't care about google, I just want to work around the Six Strikes thing. I've seen so many incidents where they didn't pirate anything and ended up having to pay $35 to get it removed.

Comment: 6strikes has little to do with your DNS server, so per your op, no there is no reason other than that google has a somewhat perverse definition of 'privacy' and may use your queries for marketing purposes, and certainly those logs could be turned over in response to subpoena, NSL, or other court order. as for 6strikes, the VPN or some form of transport encryption are the best means to defeat ISP DPI technology or endpoint analysis on the tracker side.

Comment: @Ramhound, I have found in the right circumstances, switching DNS servers can have a huge performance impact, but only if its alleviating a bottleneck that already exists. as you said, if its already working, changing it won't make much difference. I've found GRC's DNS Benchmark utility to be of great use in determining whether there is a problem and which server to use if there is one: https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm

Comment: @FrankThomas - The only time you would notice a performance increase by changing your DNS Server is when the original configuration is slow.

Comment: @chipperyman573 - If you are worried use the VPN 24/7/365 changing your DNS won't change the fact Comcast can view any unencrypted packet you receive or send.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that using a VPN means that you are trusting the VPN company instead of Google? Although the voracity of Google to gather private information is astounding, I don't believe they'll be able to connect everything you do into a package.

You can increase your privacy by logging out of your Google accounts when you research stuff, change your finger prints (different browsers with different user agents), browsing in private more, removing cookies, and much more.